# ES6 / Typescript OnClick add a class to all the TD's inside the clicked button except the first one (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>joe</td>
        <td>brown</td>
        <td><button onclick="addClasses()">Add Class to add TD's in this TR except the first one</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>bob</td>
        <td>blue</td>
        <td><button onclick="addClasses()">Add Class to add TD's in this row except the first one</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Every table row has a TD with a button.

When I click the button on a row I need every TD to be added a class except the first TD

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`When I click the button on a row I need every TD to be added a class except the first TD`

Using your existing code, you need to update the `onClick` bindings to ensure the current context of the button is preserved. Preferably you bind the events using [**addEventListener("click", addClasses);**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

`addClasses` can then use the current context to traverse back to the parent of the `td` node and get the [**firstElementChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild), skip it and iterate through the rest of the children to apply the class using [**classList.add**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

As `classList` is not supported in all versions or all element types in IE you can use [**element.className**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) instead

```js
function addClasses() {
  var node = this.parentNode.parentNode.firstElementChild || this.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild;
  
  // Ensure first  Child Selected is an element
  while(node && node.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
      node = node.nextElementSibling || node.nextSibling;
  }
  
  //skip first element child
  node = node.nextElementSibling || node.nextSibling;

  // loop through all children adding a class
  while (node && node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node !== this) {
    if(node.classList && node.classList.add){
      node.classList.add("highlight");
    } else {
      node.className += " highlight"
    }
   
    node = node.nextElementSibling || node.nextSibling;
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>joe</td>
    <td>brown</td>
    <td><button onclick="addClasses.call(this)">Add Class to add TD's in this TR except the first one</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>bob</td>
    <td>blue</td>
    <td><button onclick="addClasses.call(this)">Add Class to add TD's in this row except the first one</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> In regards to `firstElementChild || firstChild` in the above code.
>
> `firstElementChild` is not available all versions and all element types in IE which means you need to use
>   `firstChild` instead, though `firstChild` doesn't select the first
>   element node but also any `#text` or `#comment` etc..
>
> Hence to make sure you skip the first `td` element, you need to
>   quickly loop through the nodes starting at the `firstChild` (which in
>   your case is `#Text` checking the `nodeType` to ensure we skip the
>   first actual element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a class to all but the first `td` in every `tr`, why not add a single class to `table` that targets all but those?

HTML

```
<table id="table">
  ...
```

JS

```
function addClasses() {
  document.getElementById('table').classList.add('styles');
}
```

CSS

```
.styles tr td:not(:first-child) {
  // your styles here
}
```

Comment: You didn't add `id="table"` to the `table` tag.

Comment: @JosephWebber That would add the class to all rows at the same time, though it sounded like OP only wanted each row the button was clicked in be processed and not all rows at ones.

Comment: @Nope I see what you mean. Your method with DOM traversal is the better solution then.